# Unity Gradle different build types

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build

I can't find anywhere how in Unity using Gradle to add your build types to mainTemplate.gradle, and how to run different builds through in Unity without exporting

Can anyone write if there is even a way to run a build in Unity with different Build Variant?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Android Studio there you can create different Build Variants like Debug, Release. You can also take Build Variants of your Unity project in 2 ways.

1. Export your Unity project and Import it in Android Studio. From there you can create different Build Variants.

[image]

2. Check the Development Build in build settings to get a Debug build and uncheck it for Release build. Also, you can try with Build App Bundle and Script only build. These are the various Build Variants and options that available in Unity3D.

[image]